# 301 redirects using regular expressions

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am merging website A into website B.

Website A has thousands of blog posts in a variety of categories.

Heres an example : `www.sitea.com/tips/blogarticle1`

After the migration, blogarticle1 can be found at: `ww.siteb.com/blogarticle1`

Notice I have removed the '/tips' part of the URL.

How do I redirect all requests for this page (and all other pages like this) using regular expressions in the .htaccess file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the following code in sitea/.htaccess :

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/tips/(.+)$ http://newsite.com/$1
```

Refrence :

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html

Comment: This works great to redirect all traffic for /tips/*, but what if I need to redirect other categories e.g - /tutorials/* OR /blog/*? Is there an elegant way of redirecting all traffic using one line?

Comment: @Richelliot 



You can use the following pattern **^/(tips|tutorial|blog)/(.+)$**


And then replace **$1** with **$2** in the target url.